# Simple way of getting a String that represents time given a float in milliseconds

Tags: java

Given the float x = 1500, is there a built in object that can return the string "00:00:01:30" In my case the float represents milliseconds passed and I want to print the string version of it.

```
System.out.println(????.Stringvalue(x));  //for example
```

Comment: how does 00:00:01:30 relate to 1500 ?  is 1 secs? is 30 milis ?  why not use 00:00:00:000 format?

Comment: I believe because OP is using 1500 as "1 and a half seconds" so that would be "01:30" as a timestamp

Comment: @JustinYang I suspect that that is against every standard representation of time, ever.

Comment: @Dukeling I didn't say it was a good idea. It just seems that way given the example that OP used.

Comment: Ah, thanks all for the comments! I won't use a float to store milliseconds!

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there's a built-in method that does this for you, but it should be fairly simple for you to do on your own using a combination of division and the `%` modulo operator.

In this example, you know that 1500 / 1000 = 1 second. 1500 % 1000 will give you 500, or the remaining milliseconds after taking that 1 second into account. This can be extended repeatedly if you start with a larger number of milliseconds.

I'm not sure why you have 500 milliseconds written as "30", however.  Usually, after seconds would come plain milliseconds, so it would look like "00:00:01:500".

Answer (score 2):

There is no such built-in object to represent *any* sort of time duration, so no. It is fairly simple to roll your own, or [as always, just use Joda Time.](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
long x = 1500; // Don't use floats to store milliseconds.
Duration d = new Duration(x);
String formatted = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d",
    d.getStandardHours(),
    d.getStandardMinutes(),
    d.getStandardSeconds(),
    d.getMillis() % 1000);
System.out.println(formatted); // 00:00:01.500
```

Comment: I think OP wants `01:30` for some reason, as in `(d.getMillis() % 1000) * 60 / 1000` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, hugely inefficient, and total overkill, but hey-ho:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(df.format(new Date((long) x)));
```

Note: Your millis are truncated down not rounded to the nearest milli.

Comment: This prints `"19:00:01.500"` on my machine. Don't use dates to store durations. -1

Comment: Well you need to be in GMT to be fair.  Or you need to specifically create your formatter in GMT.

Comment: I've revised my response...
Happy now?

Answer (score 0):

There **IS** a way to format your value as you wish. But, you will need to convert your FLOAT to a LONG. Why use a float anyway?

You can use the [org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DurationFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html).

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(longValue);
```

Will return the standard ISO8601 format. "00:00:01:500"

Please see [Standard ISO8601 Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).